# Undefined `this` instance for angular service injection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Consider the following example:

**MyComponent.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    myService.printServiceField();
  }
}
```

**MyService.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  readonly myField= 'N/A';

  constructor() {}

  printServiceField() {
    console.log(this.myField);
  }
```

I get the following

> ERROR TypeError: "this is undefined"

Would anyone be able to explain why or point me in the right direction? If I make the myField `static` (and call it with `MyService.myField`) then it works. I'm not really looking for a solution (I have it), but rather why this is happening.

Comment: You're missing the 'this.' in front of myService.printServiceField();

Comment: Sorry, that's a separate issue though. I edited and moved the code to the constructor to highlight the original point

Comment: I don't see how this error would happen with the code you provided. This usually is an indication that the function is not called as a method of the instance.

Comment: How is `MyComponent` instance created? Are you just including its selector tag in the template of a parent component?

Comment: Seems to work with the code above [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dftxkr), not sure what issue you are experiencing. Might need a more complete code sample.

Comment: Ah. I should've recreated it myself in stackblitz. My code is a little different (the function is being called in an `ag-grid` creation. That's most likely the issue. Thanks for everyone's input

Answer (score 0):

It works fine - here is stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khbj1x